# How Moto Assist app identifies motion when Location sharing, WiFi and Mobile internet turned off?

Tags: android, mobile, gps, geolocation, motorola

I use Moto G 2nd generation mobile phone. That has a built-in app called "**Moto Assist**". After the recent update, it automatically detects my movement and switches to "*Driving*" mode when I'm travelling.
But I surprise is, how does it come to know that I'm driving even when Location, GPS, WiFi and mobile internet were turned off.

Can anyone help me understanding this?

Comment: Can anyone please answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone is using the accelerometer to detect that you're driving. This is similar to how your phone can detect a step count when you are walking. 
Its a simple low-level sensor, and doesn't require any of those additional services to detect a driving state.

What it can't do is determine where you are. It can only determine that you are likely driving.